# Creating user with plain SQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to have user who can read and insert data to all tables within one schema. I've executed following SQl statements:

```
CREATE SCHEMA ABC;
CREATE USER MyUser with PASSWORD '12345678';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ABC TO MyUser;
```

When I try to login with this user I am getting exception: Role 'MyUser' does not exists.... What is not correct here?

Answer (score 1):

How to Define Privileges Upon Role Creation
Now, we are ready to recreate the "demo_role" role with altered permissions. We can do this by specifying the permissions we want after the main create clause:

```
CREATE ROLE role_name WITH optional_permissions;
```

You can see a full list of the options by typing:

```
\h CREATE ROLE
```

We want to give this user the ability to log in, so we will type:

```
CREATE ROLE demo_role WITH LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
```

If we want to get to this state without specifying the "login" attribute with every role creation, we can actually use the following command instead of the "CREATE ROLE" command:

```
CREATE USER role_name;
```

The only difference between the two commands is that "CREATE USER" automatically gives the role login privileges.

[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-roles-and-manage-grant-permissions-in-postgresql-on-a-vps--2) or [here](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/postgresql-user-administration/) about PostgreSQL User Administration.
*Thanks*

---

**UPDATE**

We want to give this user the ability to log in, so we will type:

```
CREATE ROLE demo_role WITH LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
```

If we check the attributes `\du`

```
demo_role |                                                | {}
```

Answer (score 1):

my user name was case sensitive. using small letters solves problem.